# How i save my current location?

Tags: android, location

I create a simple  application for show me the current location ( Lat , Lon ) when i move.How i save my current location when i want?

```
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();

     }
```

Comment: By saving your current location, do you mean storing it on a database, saving it to a file, sending to your server?

Comment: Save with SharedPreferences....

Answer (score 2):

Use `SharedPreferences`.

To save the location, use:

```
getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putDouble("lng", lng).putDouble("lat", lat).commit();
```

To read the location, use:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
double lng = prefs.getDouble("lng", -1);
double lat = prefs.getDouble("lat", -1);
```

Comment: With LastknowLocation? because location changed when user move...the location must save only one time....when user press a button

Comment: So when that button is pressed, save the last known location.